# Under what conditions is this true? A finitely generated ideal minus a generator equals an ideal containing that.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $(r_1, \dots, r_{s-1}) \subset I \subset J = (r_1, \dots, r_s)$ be ideals in a commutative ring $R$.   In other words $r_s \notin I$.  Also, let $\{r_1, \dots, r_s\}$ be a minimal generating set for $J$. Then does $I = (r_1,\dots, r_{s-1})$?

My attempt.  Consider $J$ as an $R$-module of dimension $s$.  $\{r_1, \dots, r_s\}$ is a basis as it spans $J$.  If $r_i R \cap r_j R \neq 0$, then $r_i = r_j x$ for some non-unit $x \in R$ or $r_i R= r_j u R = r_j R$.  Thus $r_i R \subset r_j R$ and the set isn't minimal, therefore $r_i R \cap r_j R = 0, \ \forall i\neq j$.  Therefore $J = r_1 R \oplus \dots \oplus r_s R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Look at $(x^2 + y) \subset (x^2+y, y) = (x^2,y) \subset (x,y)$ in the polynomial ring ${\mathbb C}[x,y]$.

Note that $(x,y)$ is the radical ideal of $(x^2,y)$, so that looking at the corresponding varieties you have $V(x^2 + y) \supset V(x^2+y,y) = V(x^2,y) = V(x,y)$, which is what inspired this particular counterexample.

Comment: $(x,y) \not \subseteq (x^2,y)$...

Comment: Thanks; what was there was pretty confused - I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take a look at $\Bbb Z[x,y]$, $(x)\subseteq(x,2y)\subseteq (x,y)$.